# Populate array from XML end tags

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing

I am trying to create an array of field names that I can use later in my script.  Regular expressions are kicking my butt.  I haven't written code in a long time.  The field names are embedded in the XML tags so I figured I could extract them from the ending tag of my first row of data.  I can't see to populate the array properly.....can anyone shed some light for me?

```
my $firstLineOfXMLFile = <record>DEFECT000179<\record><state>Approved<\state><title>Something is broken<\title>

my @fieldNames = $firstLineOfXMLFile =~ m(<\(.*)>)g; #problem, can't seem to grab the text within the end tags.

print @fieldNames;
```

Thanks so much!
-Matt

Comment: Does your source file really have end tags with slashes that go the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Andy, I can make the slashes and tags anyway I want because I control the script that dumps this data out of the database.  During the export I provide the delimiter and thought that providing XML like delimiters which are really just the field names would help me parse the data later.  The export file isn't true XML.  I just thought it was close enough to give you guys an idea without bombarding you with info.  Stupid of me to make such a basic mistake.

Comment: Wait... the data is already in a database?! Why don't we just start there instead of going through this intermediate hocus-pocus?

Comment: Yes the data is exported from ClearQuest database into the format shown above, transferred to another network, and then will be uploaded.  I'm actually writing the import script and step one for me is to parse the first line of the export file to populate an array with field names.  Once I have the field names I can use them in my SQL insert statements.

Comment: XML would be a good DB output if you had a parser available. As you don't, do you have other options? Setting a single delimiter and handling it like comma-separated might work better, because you don't then have to tag match.

Comment: (And can 'parse' basic comma-sep with `split`).

Comment: So, can you export the data in a delimited format? You might be able to skip Perl altogether if you're able to export in a format the target database can understand.

Comment: And if you can't, key=value pairs are very easy to parse into perl data structures

Comment: Yes I can output in delimited format which is the way a co-worker suggested.  The problem I have though is that I need the field names to do a SQL insert which I already have figured out.  If I can't get the field names from the output file then I will need to hard-code the field names into the SQL statement for the insert.  I was hoping to grab the field names from the first row of output data, then build a SQL statement to insert the data into another database.

Comment: As long as the field ordering is consistent, and they're all matching the same column headings, this is also pretty easy to parse using hash slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data isn't XML. Your slashes are backwards. Assuming it *is* XML you're trying to parse, the answer is 'don't use regular expressions'.

They're simply not able to cope with the recursion and nesting to the degree necessary.

So with that in mind - assuming your sample data is actually well formed XML and that is a typo, something like `XML::Twig` will do it quite handily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

#extract a single field value
print $twig -> root -> first_child_text('title'),"\n";
#get a field name
print $twig -> root -> first_child -> tag,"\n";
#can also use att() if you have attributes


print "Field names:\n";
#children() returns all the children of the current (in this case root) node
#We use map to access all, and tag to read their 'name'. 
#att or trimmed_text would do other parts of the XML. 
print join ( "\n", map { $_ -> tag } $twig -> root -> children );

__DATA__
<XML>
<record>DEFECT000179</record><state>Approved</state><title>Something is broken</title>
</XML>
```

This prints:

```
Something is broken
record
Field names:
record
state
title
```

You also have a variety of other really useful tools, such as `pretty_print` for formatting your output XML, `twig_handlers` that let you manipulate XML as you parse (particularly handy for `purge`), `cut` and `paste` to move nodes around, and `get_xpath` to let you use an xpath expression to find elements based on path and attributes.

Edit: Based on comments, if you really want to extract data from:

```
</something>
```

The thing that's going wrong in your thingy is that `.*` is greedy. You either need to use a negated match - like:

```
m,</[^>]>,g
```

Or a nongreedy match:

```
m,</(.*?)>,g
```

Oh, and given you've a backslash - you need to escape it:

```
my $firstLineOfXMLFile = '<record>DEFECT000179<\record><state>Approved<\state><title>Something is broken<\title>';
my @fieldNames = $firstLineOfXMLFile =~ m(<\\(.*?)>)g;
print @fieldNames;
```

Will do the trick. (but seriously - deliberately creating something that looks like XML that isn't is a really bad thing to do)

Comment: Sobrique, the version of PERL I have access to (cqperl) is part of the IBM ClearQuest installation and is listed as version 5.8.6.  I was told that this version is stripped down and I can see that the XML:Twig package is not included.  For contract security reasons I can't easily update PERL packages.

Comment: My first question is turning out to be an embarrassment because I didn't frame my question well and provide important details.  I apologize for that.  I basically have a test file which includes hundreds of records in this format:

Comment: Cool, an 11-year-old version of Perl!

Comment: Yes sir and my Dad still drives his 1969 jeep :)

Comment: Yeah, ok. I know how that goes. But `regex` is still the wrong tool for the job. See: [parsing XHTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - HTML/XML is fundamentally more complex than `regex` supports. 
I'd suggest a change request for a new(er) perl and a couple of libraries is the _right_ way of doing it, because regex is only going to be a dirty hack at best. (Sometimes hacking is the only option though :/)

Comment: I still have some really old bits of computer hardware knocking around. I think Iv'e got an 8inch floppy drive somewhere. I don't think I'd be keen to use it for anything other than [playing music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk_XaJ7gE4Q) though.

Comment: Sobrique I appreciate the link and will go check that out now.  I thought this would be simple because I'm simply trying to find the text between "</ and >" and then push it into a array one match at a time.

Comment: For that, you just need a non-greedy match. `m,</(.*?)>,` - but I'd still urge not using something that looks a bit like XML that isn't, because that will make your future maintenance programmers very sad.

Comment: That's an antique ..... you might be able to get big money for it one day....or at least a nice donation to a museum.

Comment: Ok understood....and I am a PM just helping one of my buddies who is a developer because he is overwhelmed with work right now.  I'll look for a better way to indicate a stop and start of field data in my output file.  Thanks for the match example....I'll try to get that going in my script.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked perfectly.  Now I am going to go and study all of the responses so I understand better.  Again, I really appreciate the guidance and time you spent to answer my question especially since Im a complete stranger.  That was extremely nice of all of you.

Comment: @Matt, I love how your contract allows code from SO, but not code from CPAN. Weird. Especially since the same people submit code to both.

Comment: Change control and security policies definitely do impose constraints for reasons that might seem irrational.

Comment: @ikegami - I don't want to give you bad information but I think I am pretty close here.  We use CQPERL which is a modified version of PERL to support the IBM ClearQuest database tools.  This version of PERL runs on our production machines and we are free to code to it.  We are not allowed to install packages from the net without a million security checks and such.  Also, I'm not sure if it is even possible to install PERL packages with CQPERL since it is a special flavor of PERL from IBM to use with their database packages.  I could be wrong there and I will investigate.

Comment: Re "We are not allowed to install packages from the net without a million security checks and such." Except if they come from SO, apparently. How stupid that is! If anything, that's backwards. Widely used code is being subject a million more checks than off-the-cuff code, but it's off-the-cuff code that's more dangerous.

Comment: Sadly that is exactly the case. Code typed in is seen as "just a script" and so mostly harmless. Something installed - without a support contract - is seen as dangerous and risky. We know that it is actually more likely that malicious code on CPAN will get spotted, but it is a conversation that if you have it with a change approver, they realise that scripts are more dangerous than they thought, so they lock those down _too_rather than the other way around. It is daft, but it has also been the case at several places I have worked.