# Regexp Code Pushes Unwanted Blank Elements Into Array

Tags: regex, perl

I am populating an array of data per the example below and getting extra blank elements.  You guys helped me with a regular expression yesterday that I ran with and have been using in many different functions.  I tried to use the same logic you taught me but can't figure out why I am getting extra blank elements when extracting data between a ">" and "<".

Thank you very much!
-Matt

Data present in inputFile.txt:

```
<record>SWCR000178</record><state>Approved</state><title>Something is broken</title>
```

Perl code:

```
open $inFile, $inputFile or die $!;

while ($inFileLine = <$inFile>) {   
@fieldNames = $inFileLine =~ m(<\/(.*?)>)g;
**@fieldValues = $inFileLine =~ m(>(.*?)<)g; #This packs array with blank elements**
$recordNumber = @fieldValues[0];

print "Field Names: @fieldNames\n";
    $fieldNamesArraySize = @fieldNames;
    print "Field Names Array Size: $fieldNamesArraySize\n";
print "Field Values: @fieldValues\n";
    $fieldValuesArraySize = @fieldValues;
    print "Field Values Array Size: $fieldValuesArraySize\n";
print "Record Number: $recordNumber";

}

close $inFile;
```

Comment: use `+` instead of `*` for your pattern. `+` matches 1 or more where as `*` matches 0 or more.

Comment: As was said you are matching `><` and that's where the _blanks_ come from. As a side, does this `m(>(.*?)<)` even compile ?

Comment: Yes. Perl allows brackets as regex separators.

Comment: Using a "+" does populate the array with the correct amount of elements however the elements also now contain the <state> and <title> tags.  Printing the array yields this: SWCR000178 <state>Approved <title>Something is broken.  I could strip that out of the array I suppose but there has to be a cleaner way to do it within the Regexp.  Am I wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: @Sobrique - That's one thing I never had the guts to do in Perl, use parenthesis as delimiters.

Comment: SLN, yes the following compiles just fine: m(>(.*?)<).  Yields the wrong answer but it does compile and run just fine :)

Comment: @sln, it can improve readability. I especially like `s{xxx}{yyy}` -- pairs of matching delimiters

Comment: @glennjackman - I use `s{}{}x` sometimes with big regex when I want to span lines. But, to me, anything I see at first glance like `(...)` is going to say _list_, so, just for grins I stay away from `m()` most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: usual advice would be 'use a parser' but as this is almost certainly with reference to:  [Populate array from XML end tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244688/populate-array-from-xml-end-tags) where such is not available)

The problem you've got, is you're capturing "zero or more" characters between `><`.

So you're getting a match here:

```
</record><state>
```

And it's empty. This might do the trick though:

```
my @fieldvalues =  $inFileLine =~ m(>([^<]+)<)g;
print @fieldvalues;
```

Because it captures 'one or more' characters that are anything *other* than `<`.

```
$VAR1 = [
          'SWCR000178',
          'Approved',
          'Something is broken'
        ];
```

I'd suggest too

- turn on `strict` and `warnings`.
- use 3 arg open with lexical filehandles: `open ( my $input, '<', "filename_here") or die $!;`

And this is actually a rather handy place to use a hash:

```
#!c:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @records; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my %record = m/(\w+)        #capture one or more words 
                    \>         #literal
                    ([^<]+)    #capture one or more 'something that isn't a <'
                 /gx;          #repeat capture; ignore whitespace so I can format.
   push ( @records, \%record ); 
}

print Dumper \@records;

__DATA__
<record>SWCR000178</record><state>Approved</state><title>Something is broken</title>
```

This gives us and array of hashes containing your data.

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'state' => 'Approved',
            'title' => 'Something is broken',
            'record' => 'SWCR000178'
          }
        ];
```

More seriously though - you've just been tripped over by yet another of the reasons why parsing `XML` with regex isn't a good idea....

Comment: @ Sobrique - I have been digesting your response and greatly appreciate the great ideas.  I turned on strict and warnings.  I also edited my open command to have three arguments.   However, this:my @fieldvalues =  $inFileLine =~ m(>([^<]+)<)g; returns nothing.  The array is not populated as it cannot find a match.  Have any ideas where I could troubleshoot that?  Also, totally agree that I have been tripping over using regex with XML and am very sore :)  Thank you sir!

Comment: @ Sobrique - Thank you for the data dumper dumper code as well.  I'm going through that now.

Comment: Certainly worked in the sample I quoted. But only on the one line. Turning on "use re 'debug';" might help troubleshooting

Comment: @ Sobrique - Ofcourse you are right.  I stared at this for over and hour and then it hit me.  When I implemented what you suggested I forgot that our variable names were different (capital letter).  Thus my script was printing blank values.  Did you invent PERL?  You're the wizard!

Comment: Hardly. Just spent 15 years screwing around with it, since I outgrew 'ordinary' shell scripts.

Comment: Well, I have 15 minutes under my belt now so I am gaining on you quick :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is quite good for grinding experience. Good questions or answers help formulate your own understanding.