# Reading line by line when text spans multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a problem parsing record # SWCR000173 into @fieldValues because it spans multiple lines.  This problem could occur often in my production data set.  I understand that I am reading only one line in at a time.  I'm trying to figure out my options and have done a bunch of stackoverflow and google research.  I figured I could try to find a carriage return at the end of a line before I push to the array and concatenate with the next line.  But there might be a cleaner answer that I don't know of.  Would it be possible to look at my code and data set?  Thank you very much in advance.

Data Set Example:

```
<record>SWCR000171</record><Title>Example Single Line Title 1</Title>
<record>SWCR000172</record><Title>Example Single Line Title 2</Title>
<record>SWCR000173</record><Title>Example Multiple 
Line Title 1</Title>
<record>SWCR000174</record><Title>Example Single Line Title 3</Title>
```

Perl Code:

```
open ($inFile, '<', $inputFile) or die $!;

    while ($inFileLine = <$inFile>) {
        #Create an array of fieldnames from the line being processed    
         @fieldNames = $inFileLine =~ m(<\/(.*?)>)g;
        #Create an array of data values from the line being processed
         @fieldValues =  $inFileLine =~ m(>([^<]+)<)g;
        #Populate a variable with the record number for the line being processed
         $dbid = @fieldValues[1];

        #Submit data to database for all fields after the dbid (elements>1) 
         $entity = $session->GetEntityByDbId("SWCR",$dbid);
         $entity->EditEntity("AdminModify");
         $entity->SetFieldValue($fieldNames[$_],$fieldValues[$_]) for (2 .. $#fieldNames);
         $entity->SetFieldValue("AdminModifyReason",$inputFile);
         $entity->Validate();
         $commit = $entity->Commit();        
         }

close $inFile;
```

Comment: @toolic _Looks like_ XML is the operative phrase, but [looks can be deceiving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244688/populate-array-from-xml-end-tags). ;-)

Comment: @toolic - my data is not XML.  It is just data exported from a database in delimited format.  In my export script I place XML like tags in my output data but it is not true XML.

Comment: For this, you're going to have to _slurp_ the whole file in if you want to process multiple lines. If you have some compelling reason it can't be all read at one time, there are ways it can be done via buffering partial data, but it's very complicated. Something like `$/ = undef; my $content = <$inFile>;` Then, the regex is another issue.

Comment: Once, you've slurped in the file, a quick fix is to do a `$input =~ s/(?<=[^<>\s])\s*\n\s*(?=[^<>\s])/ /g;` then process on a line basis. Note that even though the string is now normalized, you can still get line by line. Btw, in normal html/xml, whitespace (newline) can be after the tag name, but before the `/?>`

Comment: @sln - Thank you sln, I think I am following you.  I am going to play with what you suggested to learn more.  Appreciate your time in answering this and teaching me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At risk of sounding like a broken record - the fact it looks like XML but isn't, is going to trip over future maintenance programmers in exactly the same way as you've just seen in the comments.

And worse - it's an arbitrary delimited format with line feeds - it becomes increasingly difficult to parse as a result.

Given what you have got though - your problem is that while loop. By default, `while ( <$fh> ) {` reads a line at a time.

You really need a record separator that's unique - and if your data contains linefeeds, then linefeed isn't.

From your data, I'd suggest your best bet is to set your delimiter to `</Title>`

E.g;

```
local $/ = '</Title>';
```

And then your while loop will read multiple lines until it hits that end tag. This is purely based on the assumption that - being not XML - the record ordering is consistent. Otherwise you're going to have to do something like:

```
#linefeed delim
my $buffer; 
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { 
   $buffer .= $line;
   if ( $line =~ m/>$/ ) {
            ## do processing, because the line ends in a tag

           #empty buffer
           $buffer = "";
   }
}
```

But seriously - doing fake XML like this remains a really bad idea, and this is yet another reason why. (XML parsers can handle multi-line records no problem).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  My data export script is simply executing a SQL query and populating a text file with the results.  I have the ability to change the delimiter to anything I want but it needs to be something very unique or I get into even more parsing problems when doing the insert into my other database.  I like the idea of wrapping my field data in descriptive tags because when something goes wrong during the import it's easy to push the error and record to a error file and see what went wrong easily.

Comment: But if you think it would be better maintenance wise I could use something like ~~begin_fieldname~~ and ~~end_fieldname.

Comment: My record ordering is always consistent and I love your solution of local $/ = '</Title>'; but Im not quite sure how that works quite yet.  Feverishly goggling :)  I'm going to try to put that line right before my while and see how it works.  Also, I can feed your code in the last element of my fieldNames array instead of the static </Title> value.  Having fun learning!

Comment: Perlvar is the place to look.

Comment: Changing $/ based on field names won't work, because that tells perl how much it should read first. It is a "read up to the next... " setting.  But setting it to `>\n` should mean that it reads up to the end of the line when a tag ends.

Comment: @ Sobrique - I understand what you are saying.  The >\n should work and be scalable because the DBAs could change the schema on me and </Title> will not necessarily be the last tag forever.  I could create a tag to denote the end of a line which I know is and will always be unique.  Thanks for your great suggestions and knowledge.

Comment: I read Perlvar and a couple other things and still couldn't get it working.  Then it finally dawned on me that in my test script I was trying to push a multiline value into a field that would not accept multiline.  Once I switched to a field that allowed it viola!  Having fun with PERL and actually like coming to work again.  Soon though my assignment will be done and I will be banished back to PM.  Enjoying my time helping the tech guys though!